# What python library for RFID/NFC readers in windows ?

Tags: python, .net, winapi, nfc, rfid

I'm looking for a python library to be able to work with RFID/NFC readers on windows (XP onwards). I tried RFidiot, but it did not even install for me.

Does anyone have a suggestion on which library I can use ?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use [nfcpy](https://launchpad.net/nfcpy) - although it seems quite annoying to install on Windows.